# One table in many columns (table in columns)

Tags: html, css, tabular

I have interesting problem. I need to make tables in columns. Let me explain. There are modal dialog opened and displayed 2 tables, one of the tables can be very long and need to be separated by columns.

I searched in internet but found no solution.

How can this be made in CSS/Javascript?

Comment: Is this actually tabular data, or are tables just a convenient container for your layout?

Comment: Data in tables is tabular data. Data got from JSON and parsed in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, there is a [multi-columns CSS 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) module. But as you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn), it is not very well supported by the IE.

Comment: I wanted to escape from that approach, but if there is no way to do it in <table> tag then this will be my only option. Maybe there are some super jQuery plugins?

Comment: A table can definitely not do that, because (as silly as it sounds) columns are not tabular data.

Comment: A quick google turned this up: http://welcome.totheinter.net/2008/07/22/multi-column-layout-with-css-and-jquery/

Comment: So in anyway I will need to make it with <div> ?

Comment: I made it your way with <div>. And with jQuery Columnizer plugin.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
<div id="column1">
    <table id="first_table">
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
<div id="column2">
    <table id="first_table_continued">
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </table>
    <table id="second_table">
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the correct HTML, but I think the original HTML needs to be dynamically rewritten to this format.

Comment: Uh... Interesting, but how can I do that nice in javascript.. It will be difficult to parse..

Comment: @Orb Do you need plain JavaScript code or jQuery?

Comment: @Orh Oh, do you want the number of rows per column to be automatically adjusted when browser window is resized? That would be very tricky to implement in JavaScript but if you want fixed number of rows per column that's not very hard to write.

Comment: I use jQuery. There is max tree columns. I need something dynamicaly from one to tree columns.

Comment: Ok, I made it to work with Columnizer plugin and with divs. Now there is another problem with columnizer :)